# setting variables values to empty string in except clause in python

Tags: python, try-catch, except

My problem is , i am setting some values to the multiple variables in try clause. what i want is  , when one of the values of the variables is not available , it should be empty string in except clause but only for those variables which are not available.
for your reference , here is my try clause...

```
  try:
        app_source_name_attr = json_data["APP_DATA"]['metadata']["app_source_name"]
        source_type_attr = json_data['APP_DATA']['metadata']['source_attributes_jsonb']['source_type']
        utm_source_attr = json_data['APP_DATA']['metadata']['source_attributes_jsonb']['utm_source']
        utm_medium_attr = json_data["APP_DATA"]['metadata']['source_attributes_jsonb']['utm_medium']
        utm_campaign_attr = json_data["APP_DATA"]["metadata"]["source_attributes_jsonb"]["utm_campaign"]
        utm_campaignid_attr = json_data["APP_DATA"]["metadata"]["source_attributes_jsonb"]["utm_campaignid"]
```

if values are not available , i want to pass empty string to that variable otherwise value should be passed which i set in try clause.
so , how except clause should be ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put empty string values before `try` clause, one variable for example:

```
app_source_name_attr = ''
try:
    app_source_name_attr = json_data["APP_DATA"]['metadata']["app_source_name"]
except Exception:
    pass
print(app_source_name_attr)  # will print empty string if exception occured inside try-except block
```

Comment: worked like charm brother. Thanks a ton. I was wondering if there is any another way to do that ? this worked fine for me though and thanks for that.

Comment: Another ways maybe more difficult. For example, if you want to set `app_source_name_attr = ''` in `except` clause, you need to check if the variable is defined or not. By the way, you can mark my answer as accepted, if it solves your problem.